# Beamer: 'references' wrongly appears in the table of contents

Tags: beamer, biblatex, table-of-contents

In a Beamer document I am including the bibliography at the end using:

```
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength{\hoffset}{.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{References}
     \printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{frame}
\endgroup
```

using the packages:

```
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{references.bib}
```

and generate a table of contents at the beginning using:

```
\begin{frame}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

The 'references' wrongly appears in the table of contents as shown below:

[image]

How should I remove the 'references' from the table of contents? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post a lot of disconnected code fragments. Instead please always make a small but compilable test document so we don't have to puzzle together all your code fragments and guess the missing pieces.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `heading=bibintoc` option explicitly adds the references to the toc. So to remove them from the toc, just don't explicitly add them.

```
\documentclass{beamer}


\useoutertheme{sidebar}
\usepackage[american]{babel} 
\usepackage{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\vspace{-0.5cm}
\frametitle{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
    
\begin{frame}
    \cite{knuth:ct}
\end{frame} 
    
  
\begingroup
\makeatletter
\setlength{\hoffset}{.5\beamer@sidebarwidth}
\makeatother

\begin{frame}[noframenumbering,plain,allowframebreaks]\frametitle{References}
     \printbibliography%[heading=bibintoc]
\end{frame}
\endgroup

  
\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help! It solved my problems.